# Xenforo Facebook integration redirect_uri error

Tags: facebook, facebook-login, facebook-authentication, xenforo

Created Facebook App made it public.

[Basic Settings screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47eM4.jpg)

[Advanced Settings screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ja2Cr.jpg)

While testing on Xenforo I see following message:

Error validating verification code. Please make sure your redirect_uri is identical to the one you used in the OAuth dialog request.

I followed instuction provided by Xenforo

How to solve it?

Comment: Is your redirect URI really just `site.com`? Go check the value of the `redirect_uri` parameter in the login dialog call. You have to specify the URL used there as a Valid OAuth Redirect URI.

Comment: @CBroe please, think that site.com will be replaced. Here is link of error:

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=875587212494501&scope=public_profile,email&state=a47dab9813e3589429df3a2660f05f5c&redirect_uri=http://kyrgyzgroup.com//register/facebook

Comment: So the value of your `redirect_uri` parameter is `http://kyrgyzgroup.com//register/facebook`, and that means you need to input that same value as a Valid OAuth Redirect URI. (And before doing that, you should see to it that the double slash in there gets removed – probably a configuration issue, looks like you input the base URL with a trailing slash, or the path with a leading one, somewhere where it is expected without one.)

Comment: facebook automatically adds slash when I save. I tried to go to link with one slash, shows error

Comment: Solved by setting websites URL without last slash, like "http://www.example.com" on Xenforo settings ---> main settings